# 15A versus 20A circuit for floor tile heat

Tags: electrical

OK here is my situation. Adding tile floor to a 50 SF bath, want to put heat under the tiles. The manufacturer says the heating system (pulling 3-4 amps max) MUST be on its own circuit and be GFCI protected. No idea why they need a separate circuit as they advertise how little electricity is used.

Fishing wires from my panel to the bath, and using a remodel box, OK I can do that...

But, this would be considerably cheaper if I used a 15A breaker and 14/2 wire. I see no reason for this circuit to be 20A and the manufacturer does not require that.

I can get a 15A GFCI, but it has outlets on it, which defeats the "separate circuit" and why would I want 20A and 15A GFCI plugs right next to each other in the same wall? Dead front GFCIs are available, but I can only find them in 20A.

I can get a 15A GFCI breaker for my box and run it that way, but that is clearly the most expensive option.

To me the simplest solution is to use the 20A dead front GFCI on a 15A circuit. As there are no plugs anywhere on the circuit, adding things later would be nearly impossible given space constraints, and the heat draws 3-4 Amps, what is the issue?

Comment: Often the floor thermostat includes GFCI.  If yours does not, consider upgrading to one that does, then you don't have to provide GFCI, just a straight run from an ordinary 15A breaker to the thermostat.

Comment: If the 15 A breaker is "considerably cheaper" then you're shopping at the wrong place.

Comment: Regarding the separate circuit: I am guessing that the manufacturer is following a product safety guideline. Since it does not provide its own GFCI and would require protection from the supplying circuit, it would be generally unsafe in a bathroom to have a GF event -that might cause a minor shock on a wet slippery floor- also trip the lighting and plunge the space with closed & locked door in total darkness.

Answer (score 3):

15A breaker and 20A breaker for any given panel should cost exactly the same, if not extremely close. Quick search at [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com) - current pricing Eaton BR 15A and 20A both $7.37, Eaton CH both $12.98, Square D Homeline both $6.63, etc.

But 14/2 cable will normally be less expensive than 20A cable, and for a dedicated circuit that requires well under 12A continuous, there is no reason to use more than a 15A circuit and 14 AWG cable.

So now we get to the GFCI alternatives:

- GFCI/breaker - almost always significantly more expensive than the other options. However, it does not require an additional device in a separate box, so that mitigates some of the cost *when a GFCI/receptacle is not appropriate*, such as in a dedicated circuit.
- GFCI/receptacle - can't do that because it violates manufacturer instructions as it is then no longer a dedicated circuit. This is actually a code requirement if the device uses at least 50% of the circuit capacity. It may be that the manufacturer requires a dedicated circuit for *all* of their in-floor heating products because *some* of them use more than half of a typical circuit capacity, but only the manufacturer can answer that.
- GFCI/deadfront - This is the logical solution to "less money but still dedicated". Keep in mind that this should either be right next to the breaker panel (normally an extra box there is no big deal and doesn't cause any aesthetic, space or wiring concerns) or near the point of use. The problem is that you really shouldn't put a GFCI on or next to the floor - it will get wet and that's not good. So that means putting it in another box in the bathroom, either by itself (extra cost) or in a box that also has other receptacles and/or switches.

A GFCI/deadfront *can* have higher current *capacity* than the circuit - i.e., 20A on a 15A circuit. There is really no harm doing so. You can't put a 20A receptacle on a 15A circuit (but the other way around is OK and quite common) because someone could plug in a 20A appliance and that would cause problems. But a GFCI/deadfront is only connected to either hardwired devices (like your floor heater) or receptacles (and the regular rules for receptacles on a particular circuit applies). Similar would be using a 20A-rated toggle switch on a 15A circuit - it won't hurt anything at all - or even using 12 AWG wire on a 15A circuit.

Comment: Yes, the cost was the cost of the wiring, not the breaker. I agree that the dead front GFCI is the solution. Two boxes in same wall cavity should not be a problem, but I will check if the thermostat assembly includes GFCI protection.